# Where is downloaded data saved?

Tags: data

When using functions such as FinancialData or CountryData, on many occasions, Mathematica needs to connect to the Wolfram Research Server to download the necessary information to evaluate these commands. Sometimes internet connection is not available and other times the process is just redundant. Therefore, is there a folder or directory in which the data downloaded is stored? Is it cached? Is there a way to access it?  How does this work?

Comment: Depends on the functionality, but typically somewhere in `$UserBaseDirectory` (e.g. in `Paclets`) or in `$LocalBase`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer from a [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/163316/where-is-downloaded-data-saved#comment432577_163316):

> Depends on the functionality, but typically somewhere in `$UserBaseDirectory` (e.g. in Paclets) or in `$LocalBase`. – ilian Jan 9 at 1:54

Answer (score 0):

It should save into your current directory, which you can see with the command

```
Directory[]
```

You can use use the command `SetDirectory["directoryname"]` to change the current directory to what you want.  If you have loaded your `.nb` file from a directory or saved it to a directory, you can specify

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
```

and your current directory will be the same as the directory your notebook is saved to.  This doesn't work if your current notebook is brand new and has not been saved yet, because then there is no directory assigned to the notebook yet.

Comment: I don't think so. Curated data is not saved like data you save from your notebook.

Comment: That's true for data that you do not specifically save yourself.  There is data in "Paclets/Repository" in the $UserBaseDirectory[].  The data is in binary .wdx files, so it is not particularly readable.

Comment: I read the question as the OP asking about curated data that has been downloaded by reference and not specifically saved by the OP. therefore, I don't think this answers the question.